# How can I keep track of a "like" system on android?

Tags: java, android

I am currently making an android app for a friend who is a photographer where he will display his images in a RecyclerView. We would like to have sort of like a "like" feature where they can like his pictures. My question is, how would I keep track of the "likes"? What I mean is, how can I make it so that if someone already liked it, they cannot exit the app, come back and like it again? I thought about adding a +1 every time there was a like to the image properties in a database, but how can I keep them from exiting the app, coming back, and liking it again? TIA!

Comment: If it matters only on local level - use a database. However, on Android you can just purge all app's data and thus delete the likes. So in order to save them, you have to have a backend server which would have a database connection and on each like you will write to the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your problem is just a matter of identity. To achieve your goal, you should have a way to identify every piece of the pictures and each of the person who will give up-votes to these pictures.

If  you can identify different pictures and different users, you can achieve your goal by either of the following ways:

1. For each of the pictures store all the users that have liked it. And every time a user want to like a picture, you should check whether he is in this collection or not. Only add the identity of the user to this collection if he is not in this set which means he did not like this picture before
2. Or you can store all the pictures that are liked by the user.

Which way is better depends on your other use cases.

To identify your pictures you can just assign a distinct name for each of the picture.
So you can see the key problem it **how to identify your users**.

Since you do not provide **a detailed use case of the like action**, I will describe some general ideas.

- If you have a server
  - If the user must login, you can identify your users by their login id
  - If your user do not need to login, you can use some other information to identify your user for example their device id, MAC address or other device-specific indentity.
- If you do not have a server, then how can you identify all the users that use the same device? The only way I can come up with is that, you must implement a local user system and ask the user to log in before they want to like a photo.

Comment: Thank you! Everyone had great answers but I thought yours was the best! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you have so signing in users my guess is that you can't. You could save on a hidden file on the device the ids of the photos the device "liked" but this can be easily deleted if the user deletes the apps cache files or uninstall/reinstall.

Not an android expert here, just mho

Answer (score 0):

With login:
In your Database there are "User", "Image" and "User_like_image"
You just have to check if this user didnt already upvoted the image

without login:
You locally store the ID of every images he upvoted

Answer (score 0):

A rough idea: with each item that can be liked store a list of ids that liked it on the server. Your like count is equals to the list length.

On each device generate a random device id token (`UUID.randomUUID()` is always a good candidate), persist it locally on the device (e.g. in `SharedPreferences` - wiping the app data will kill it but that can't be solved reliably) and send it to the server with each request.

The server can now

1. tell you whether you already liked an image which is nice to see on the device and
2. reject multiple likes from the same device

A simpler approach: store locally in e.g. `SharedPreferences` that you liked the item. Then behave nicely and don't send another like request to your server backend when you see that you already did. Can be abused because it relies no the client software to be nice but I doubt a small photographer app needs to care too much about that.

A more elaborate approach: require user accounts. That works accross devices and persists through app uninstalls. People that go far enough to create multiple accounts to vote multiple times can't be stopped anyways. The big downside is that people will most likely not want to have another account just to like some photos. Would not recommend if avoidable.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to avoid having people like the same item twice was:

Have 2 states with the same button. If you clicked on "like" the button state changes to "Remove Like" Save the state of the button in shared prefs and check the state before a click is given.

Example:

button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    String ButtonText = button.getText().toString();
    if(ButtonText.equals("Like"){
        //code for Like

        button.setText("Remove Like");
    }
    else{
        //code for remove Like
        button.setText("Like");
    }
}
```

});